# Timber: Get single image from media library with all attributes

Tags: theme-development

In my [Timber](https://www.upstatement.com/timber/)-based theme, I'm getting a single image from the media library using the following (based on [Timber/Image](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-image/)):

```
<img src="{{ Image(678).src }}" alt="{{ Image(678).alt }}" srcset="{{ Image(678).srcset }}" sizes="{{ Image(678).img_sizes }}" />
```

However it's silly to repeatedly state the image id for each attribute.

Is there a single command that can spit out a fully populated image instance or does this call for a custom PHP function, and make it available to Timber?

---

For reference, the above code outputs this:

```
<img src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/myimage.png" alt="This is the image!" srcset="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/myimage.png 1052w, https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/myimage-150x150.png 150w, https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/myimage-150x150@2x.png 300w, https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/myimage-768x768.png 768w, https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/myimage-1024x1024.png 1024w, https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/myimage-300x300@2x.png 600w" sizes="(max-width: 1052px) 100vw, 1052px">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's as simple as:

```
{% set post_image = Image(678) %}
<img src="{{ post_image.src }}" alt="{{ post_image.alt }}" srcset="{{ post_image.srcset }}" sizes="{{ post_image.img_sizes }}" />
```

Ref: [Twig `set`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html)